# Why this gradle build script is not compiling java class?

Tags: gradle, cascading

I am trying to use `Cascading` in my Hadoop project. I am trying to implement first example given in `Enterprise Data Workflows with Cascading` book. I have written java class which contains `Cascading` related code and I have another `build.graddle` file which is supposed to compile that java class and build jar file out of it.

My folder structure is as follows :

- main_folder

  - impatient

    - Main.java
    - build.gradle

My `build.gradle` file looks as below :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

archivesBaseName = 'impatient'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo name: 'conjars', url: 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
}
ext.cascadingVersion = '2.1.0'
dependencies {
    compile( group: 'cascading', name: 'cascading-core', version: cascadingVersion )
    compile( group: 'cascading', name: 'cascading-hadoop', version: cascadingVersion )
}
jar {
    description = "Assembles a Hadoop ready jar file"
    doFirst {
        into( 'lib' ) {
            from configurations.compile
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes( "Main-Class": "impatient/Main" )
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle clean jar` command from command prompt, I get build successful message. I tried to run this jar file using

`hadoop jar impatient.jar <input file path> <output file path>`

command but then it gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: impatient.Main` exception.

So I checked contentes of jar file and found that that jar does not contain `impatient/Main.class` file.

Please note that **I do not know anything about gradle**.

Request someone to please tell me if there is anything wrong with gradle script or I am making some mistake.

Thanks !!!

Comment: I'm not sure here but I think "Main-Class": "impatient.Main" is the way to go, or even "mainClassName=impatient.Main". Check http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move your source file to

`main_folder/impatient/src/main/java/Main.java`

but leave build.gradle file where it is.

By default, Gradle uses `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` to look for production and test java sources (relative to root folder, which is `impatient` in your case)